# Nested foreaches into a chained linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know if it is even possible to do what I think, but I guess it worths to try :)

Can I combine these two nested foreaches?

```
foreach ( var dept in curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments )
{
    foreach ( var personnel in dept.Personnels )
    {
        myPersonnels.Add(personnel);
    }
}
```

I want to turn this nested for each into a chained linq expression. Is is possible? If so how?

Comment: whilst both answers below would work would help if we knew what myPersonnels was

Comment: @Yakyb Yeah, I'd imagine it might have an `AddRange` on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is personnel preference (see what I did there?), but I like sticking with functional programming if that's what I start with.

You can replace the `foreach` language construct with the `List<T>.ForEach` method.

```
curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments
    .SelectMany(department => department.Personnels)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(personnel => myPersonnels.Add(personnel);
```

Typically, we'd use a shorter argument name for the delegates:

```
curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments
    .SelectMany(d => d.Personnels)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => myPersonnels.Add(p);
```

And, if `myPersonnels` is just a collection, you can create it outright:

```
var myPersonnels = curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments
    .SelectMany(d => d.Personnels)
    .ToList();
```

Or, if it's already a `List<T>`, you can add an `IEnumerable<T>` to it:

```
myPersonnels.AddRange(
    curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments
        .SelectMany(d => d.Personnels)
);
```

Comment: I like this answer the best since it does the add operation in same line too.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach ( var personnel in
 curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments.SelectMany(x=> x.Personnels))
{
    myPersonnels.Add(personnel); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`SelectMany<TSource, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var allPersonnel = curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments.SelectMany(dept => dept.Personnels);

// If there is no AddRange method:
foreach (var personnel in allPersonnel)
    myPersonnels.Add(personnel);

// If there is an AddRange method:
myPersonnels.AddRange(personnel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ken is almost right, but if I'm right the myPersonnels list is an external one where you want to copy the result of your "query". The first two answers are very readable, but if you want to code it shortly, you can write this:

```
curDevice.Personnel.Department.Company.Departments
    .SelectMany(x => x.Personnels) // selecting the personnels
    .ToList()
    .Foreach(myPersonnels.Add); // iterate trough the personnels list and copy them into the external list
```